# Rails multiple join with where query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have a problem with constructing some complex query in my Rails app. I have three models:

```
class Partner < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :rental_company
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable, :confirmable
end

class RentalCompany < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :owners, class_name: 'Partner'
  has_many :cars
end

class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :rental_company
end
```

Partner object has the method "confirmed?" from devise. And now I want to find all cars where car rental company partner confirmed? is true. How can I do that?

Comment: There should be `has_many :cars` in `RentalCompany`.

Comment: Yes, I forgot about this relationship. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
Car.joins(rental_company: :owners).where('partners.confirmed_at IS NOT NULL')
```

According to [this](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Confirmable#confirm%21-instance_method), Devise `Confirmable` module sets `confirmed_at` column as current time. So it should be enough to find `partners` records that have `confirmed_at` value other than `NULL`.

Comment: @MateuszUrbański I edited my answer. It should work now.